# I messed up my Ubuntu installation, how to fix it

Tags: ubuntu, display-manager, unity

After installing various desktop environments, just for testing purposes, I messed up my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and now,

1. The clock has vanished from the top menu bar
2. Unity tweak tool has gone
3. I get unmet dependency errors when installing unity tweak tool

[image]

I tried many answers provided in Askubuntu but no success. Can you help me to fix my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please add the error message

Comment: @GAD3R thank you. Added an image, this is just one.

Comment: Run the following command : `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common`

Comment: Then run  `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service`

Comment: after running that I get [this error](http://telegra.ph/terminal-12-17)

Comment: @NuwanThisara: for the future copy(&paste) also works in the terminal, so it can be searched & found by other users or ever experts to answer...

Comment: @GAD3R After running the new command I get [this](http://telegra.ph/ter-12-17)

Comment: Purge , remove and reinstall `unity-tweak-tool`

Comment: @GAD3R when I try to purge it says "Unty tweak tool is not installed, so not removed"

Comment: Run `sudo apt install aptitude && sudo aptitude -f install unity-tweak-tool`

Comment: If doesn't work Run `sudo aptitude` , check the resolver tab it will assist you to solve the dependencies

Comment: Any ppa's?  `apt-cache policy | egrep -i -v translat`  and `dpkg -l | egrep -i unity | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy`

Comment: @GAD3R sudo aptitude -f install unity-tweak-tool  fixed most dependancy problems as it suggested me to do a series of YES and NO. Now unity tweak tool is installed and time is shown on the top panel, but only in 12 hour format, if I choose 24 hours, nothing is shown.

Comment: From the menu bar clic on the clock >Date & Time Settings > clock then choose 24h

Comment: @GAD3R Did that, clock disappears. only 12 hour format works. strange? anyway you helped a lot. thanks for that.

Comment: Try to install `clock-up` package [tuto](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/06/ubuntu-touch-lockscreen-app-on-desktop/)

Comment: @GAD3R got a point, but there is a problem. When I select SECONDS to show in 24 hour format, it does not show, when I remove the tick in front of seconds it shows in 24 hour format.

Comment: Try this answer from [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/41961/498780)

Comment: @GAD3R just did that, when I choose SECONDS, the clock disappears

Answer (score 0):

To problem is solved by installing `aptitude` and following the suggestions proposed by the resolver to fix the unmet dependencies  :

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude -f install unity-tweak-tool
```